# Set Data Type in mySQL

Tags: mysql

My knowledge of relational databases is more limited, but is there a SQL command that can be used to create a column that contains a set in each row?

I am trying to create a table with 2 columns. 1 for specific IDs and a 2nd for sets that correspond to these IDs.

I read about

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html

However, the set data type requires that you know what items may be in your set. However, I just want there to be a variable-number list of items that don't repeat.

Comment: You don't want that, look into [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you probably want a second table with `(id,value)`, where a 2nd (3rd, 4th,..) values would be a _new_ row with the same `id` again, and the new/other `value`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would be much better to create that list of items as multiple rows in a second table.  Then you could have as many items in the list you want, you could sort them, search for a specific item, make sure they're unique, etc.

See also my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: Would that mean that I would need to create a separate table for each list? Hence, I would need either a different name for each of the list tables?

Comment: Yes.  Think of this analogy: you would also need a different variable name for each value or array you use in application code!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no MySQL data type for arbitrary sets. You can use a string containing a comma-delimited list; there are functions like `FIND_IN_SET()` that will operate on such values.

But this is poor database design. If you have an open-ended list, you should store it in a table with one row per value. This will allow them to be indexed, making searching faster.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support arrays, lists or other data structures like that. It does however support strings so use that and `FIND_IN_SET()` function:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

"SET" data type won't be a good choice here. 
You can use the "VARCHAR" and store the values in CSV format. You handle them at application level.
Example: INSERT into my_table(id, myset) values(1, "3,4,7");

Comment: I would never suggest someone store a delimited list in a database column.  See the response by @BillKarwin above. And see his other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574